# What is the etymology and meaning of Oss?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, jujutsu, japanese

I've moved to a new location, and have started training with a new Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu school. My previous school made absolutely no use of the word "oss". It is, however, ubiquitous with my new school.

At times, it is phrased as a question, "Oss?" To which we reply, "Oss."

I realize it is a response, usually affirmative, or in agreement, basically meaning "yes", but I suspect there is more to it.

If I post a Jiu-Jitsu photo to Instagram, for example, some users will reply with "oss" indicating some show of support or camaraderie I presume.

It seems to be used for a variety of different reasons.

I have read the similar question / answer – [When is it appropriate to respond with osu?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6600/when-is-it-appropriate-to-respond-with-osu) – but the OP's question is specifically about *when* to say "osu" not *what* "oss" means. None of the answers given to that post provide any citations or references for their answers, and [only one specifically answers the OP's original question of "when"](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/7077/7401) to say "osu".  I presume "osu" to be an ancestor of the presently used "oss". Or is "oss" some slang derivation?

What is the etymology and meaning of "oss"?

Comment: Have you seen this post with 3 theories about the origins/meaning of oss/osu? [The Meaning of "OSS" / "OSU"](http://www.karatebyjesse.com/meaning-oss-osu-japanese/)

Comment: @HugoFerreira - Rather than point someone to an outside link, perhaps you could post an answer summarizing the information here, and use the link as a reference?

Comment: @JohnP it's a very obvious 3rd place result in a simple Google search for “meaning of oss”… checking first if the OP thinks it addresses his question

Comment: @HugoFerreira Thanks for the suggested link. There are a lot of articles out there, but few, if any, have citations or references to legitimize their claims or opinions.  A lot of them are copy-cat articles as well.  I will continue to dig and share as I have time.

Comment: @mattm - I am reluctant to mark it as a duplicate where the primary answer to the question is a non referenced opinion from a user that removed their account.

Comment: @johnp Part of the problem is the karatebyjesse source only appears as a comment in the previous question. Apparently it was left as an (unfinished) exercise to that asker to write a proper answer citing it.

Comment: @JohnP Is it fair to ask that the duplicate flag be removed? Have I researched and distinguished this Q & A as uniquely qualified to stand on its own?

Comment: @jacefarm - I can remove the comment, but the 4 votes to close would remain anyway. Those are cast by members of the community, it would be up to them to retract the votes.

Comment: @JohnP 4 votes to close, and down-votes on both the Q & A... Sheesh.  Tough crowd...

Comment: @jacefarm If you have a problem with down and close votes, you should open a meta question about this. I would be happy to tell you why I think both your question and answer are lacking there.

Comment: @JohnP Just because a question has no good answer should bear no relation whatsoever as to whether this question is or is not a duplicate.

Comment: I will edit based on this [discussion in Meta](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/527/why-do-flags-for-this-similar-yet-different-question-persist). Oss!

Comment: I am in favor of this question being deleted as unsalvageable in favor of a [new and improved question](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/7939/why-should-oss-be-used-in-brazilian-jiu-jitsu) inspired by this [discussion on Meta](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/527/why-do-flags-for-this-similar-yet-different-question-persist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oss is...

### Also known as

Osu or Ossu ([オッス](http://gogen-allguide.com/o/ossu.html))

### The Meaning of Oss

- [good morning](http://gogen-allguide.com/o/ossu.html) ([additional reference](https://www.wikiwand.com/ja/%E6%8A%BC%E5%BF%8D))
- [persevering when pushed](https://www.attacktheback.com/what-does-oss-mean/)
- [to push and to suffer](http://www.minrec.org/wilson/pdfs/Language%20-%20The%20%27oss%27%20greeting.pdf)<sup>1</sup>
- [to keep the faith](http://www.minrec.org/wilson/pdfs/Language%20-%20The%20%27oss%27%20greeting.pdf)<sup>1</sup>
- [the equivalent of a warm-handshake](http://www.minrec.org/wilson/pdfs/Language%20-%20The%20%27oss%27%20greeting.pdf)<sup>1</sup>
- [hello, yes, or I understand](http://www.uskyokushin.com/osu.htm), ([additional reference](https://www.bjjee.com/articles/the-meaning-of-oss-or-osu/))
- [a greeting used by young Bushi warriors of the Saga clan in the 18th and 19th centuries](http://the-martial-way.com/history-of-osu-oss/)<sup>2</sup>
- [acknowledging an opponent's good, hard technique, or, their skill](http://www.uskyokushin.com/osu.htm), ([additional reference](https://www.bjjee.com/articles/the-meaning-of-oss-or-osu/))
- [the absolute and unfaltering devotion needed to "scale the cliff" of a martial art discipline](http://www.uskyokushin.com/osu.htm)
- good job, rad, or kewl brah<sup>3</sup>

From Kyokushin Karate:

> [This strength of character develops in hard training and is known as Osu no Seishin 押忍の精神 (the Spirit of Osu).  The word Osu comes from Oshi Shinobu 押し忍ぶ, which means "to persevere whilst being pushed".  It implies a willingness to push oneself to the limits of endurance, to persevere under any kind of pressure.](http://www.uskyokushin.com/osu.htm)

From Carlson Gracie's philosophy of Brazilian Jiu-Jitsu:

> [In BJJ, Carslon Gracie introduced the use of the word “Oss” and it rightly fits the mentality of Carlson Gracie Jiu-Jitsu: Brave, determined, strong, smashing. It’s a bit similar to the war cry “Hoo-ah” that you will hear U.S. Marines use.](https://www.bjjee.com/articles/the-meaning-of-oss-or-osu/)

### The Etymology of Oss, Osu, and Ossu

#### Osaku

- [オッスは、戦前、京都にあった武道専門学校の生徒の間から生まれた言葉で、「おはようございます」の略。... 「おはようございます」が「おはよーっす」となり、「おわーす」「おす」と変化していった ... 挨拶として用いられる「オッス」は「おはようございます」が略されたものだが、](http://gogen-allguide.com/o/ossu.html):: *"Osaku" stands for "Good morning" in the words born among students of the martial arts vocational school which was in Kyoto before the war. ... "Good morning" was changed to "Oh yeah," and it changed to "Ohuu" and "Osu". ... "Osu" used as a greeting is the abbreviation of "Good morning".*

Meaning, good morning.

#### Osu-ni

- [その「おす」に、武道の精神である「自我を抑え我慢する」という意味の「押して忍ぶ」が当てられ、漢字では「押忍」と表記されるようになった。](http://gogen-allguide.com/o/ossu.html):: *To "push and endure" meaning "to hold back the ego" in the spirit of martial arts in which it was applied. In Kanji, it was written as "Osu-ni".*

Meaning, to push on and endure while also holding back the ego.

#### Oshi Shinobu

- [押し](http://www.uskyokushin.com/osu.htm) :: *Oshi meaning "Push"*
- [忍ぶ](http://www.uskyokushin.com/osu.htm) :: *Shinobu  meaning "to Endure"*
- [to persevere while being pushed](http://www.uskyokushin.com/osu.htm)

Meaning, patience, determination, and perseverance.

#### Onegaishimasu

- [おねがいします](https://www.bjjee.com/articles/the-meaning-of-oss-or-osu/) :: *Onegaishimasu or Onegai Shimasu meaning "Please"*, ([additional reference](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-the-difference-between-kudasai-and-onegaishimasu-3572604))

Meaning, a polite or honorific way of requesting something from another, of saying "please".

#### Ohayossu, Ohayoosu, and Oossu

From Jesse Enkamp of [Karate by Jesse](http://www.karatebyjesse.com), who quotes Dr. Mizutani Osamu<sup>4</sup>:

- [オハヨス](http://www.karatebyjesse.com/meaning-oss-osu-japanese/) :: *"Ohayossu!”, “Ohayoosu!”, “Oossu!” meaning "Hey ya!"*

Meaning, "hey ya", by male runners in the midst of jogging, responding in rougher, masculine ways to Dr. Mizutani's greeting to them of "Ohayo gozaimasu!" (good morning).<sup>4</sup>

### Conclusion

The term **oss**, which is derived from **osu** or **ossu**, has a variety of interpretations and meanings.

But there is a common essence shared among them all.

Oss means having humility and an acknowledgement of respect for the person to whom it is being spoken.  It means to have a perspective of strength and perseverance towards a challenge that is being addressed, or, that is to be endured.  And in more general or colloquial contexts, it operates as an affirmative acknowledgment, a greeting, or a polite request.

<sup>1</sup><sub>FEY, B.R., 1994, *To oss or not to oss: that is the question*, *Dojo Magazine*, Winter 1994, p. 80-81</sub>
<sup>2</sup><sub>Tsunetomo, Yamamoto, *Hagakure, The Book of the Samurai*, ~ 1709-1716</sub>
<sup>3</sup><sub>These are general impressions from training, class, and, sigh, bro-jitsu experiences.</sub>
<sup>4</sup><sub>Mizutani, Osamu, *Japanese: The Spoken Language in Japanese Life*, Tokyo, Sotakusha, Inc., 1981, p. 59-60</sub>

Comment: I will edit based on this [discussion in Meta](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/527/why-do-flags-for-this-similar-yet-different-question-persist). Oss!

Comment: This thread is also relevant: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54045/the-etymology-and-meaning-of-oss-osu-ossu

Answer (score 2):

We don't use the phrase in my school, Karate or Aikido.  But I know of some who do; and not being a part of them, I admit ignorance on the subject.

However, this article might be helpful:

[The History & Origins of “Osu!”](http://www.karatebyjesse.com/meaning-oss-osu-japanese/)

Yes, it does discuss "when", but it also discusses the etymology.  And there is the implication that there isn't a definitive source out there.  I like KarateByJesse and his articles; but he doesn't source this one, and so, you might want to take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, a definitive resource does seem hard to come by... The article you mention is now a part of my research.

Comment: Wigwam - Since links decay, could you summarize the pertinent points here?